# Cooldown Ability in MonoGame

Tags: c#, xna, delay, monogame

I have an ability for the player.  I only want the player to be able to use this ability once every 5 seconds.  I can always put this in my game loop:

```
Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    GamePadState controller = GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One);
    cooldown--;
    if(cooldown <= 0 && controller.Buttons.A == ButtonState.Pressed)
    {
        UseAbility();
        cooldown = 5000;
    }
}
```

But I am looking for something that will be exactly 5 seconds (opposed to 5000 update()'s), and I would like something more elegant than this barbarian code.  Any suggestions?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `GameTime` variable. You could try something like this:

```
float cooldowntime = 0;
Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    GamePadState controller = GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One);

    cooldowntime += gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds; 
    //if you are using XNA 3.1 or earlier, use GameTime.ElapsedRealTime

    if(cooldowntime >= 5000 && controller.Buttons.A == ButtonState.Pressed)
    {
         UseAbility();
         cooldowntime = 0;
    }
}
```

Using this, every update method, the `cooldowntime` will get the elapsed gametime in milliseconds added to it (if you are using XNA 3.1, you can use `ElapsedRealTime`, which is the time in "real life" elapsed. This would be useful if you get under 60fps). Then if `cooldowntime` is greater that 5000ms (5 seconds), the ability will be enabled for one update method. If you wanted to be more precise than `GameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds`, you could use a `Stopwatch` or `DateTime.Now`, for example. HTH

Note: If you get exactly 60fps per update, `ElapsedGameTime` should be perfectly accurate.

***EDIT:*** To reduce the lines used, try this:

```
float cooldowntime = 0;
Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    GamePadState controller = GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One);

    cooldowntime = (cooldowntime >= 5000 && controller.Buttons.A == ButtonState.Pressed) ? 0 : cooldowntime + gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds; 
    if (cooldowntime == 0) UseAbility(); 
    // we know to use the ability if cooldowntime = 0 since it will only equal zero
    // when cooldowntime >= 5000 and the button is pressed.
}
```

Comment: Upvote for fixing the timing issue. Any ideas on cleaning up the code a bit?  (It's not bad in this example, but in my game, using this method is quite messy.)

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by quite messy? Is the `cooldowntime` variable making it messy?

Comment: Yes, I was hoping to find a one-liner for my if statement.  Otherwise I have 20 extra variables to keep track of.  It isnt a huge deal, but Ive already got a cluster**** going on with my code.  Was hoping to have one nice elemnt to it :)

Comment: heh not exactly what i was hoping for, but i think thats cuz i wanted something that doesnt exist.  i appreciate the tip on elapsedtime.  thanks!!

Comment: Sure! Glad it helped. Good luck with your game!

Answer (score 1):

Simple routine, just call it with number of milliseconds you need to wait, on the call side just do an if statement like:-

```
if(DelayGame(gameTime, 5000))
{
  // after 5 seconds
  // do this
}
```

here it is:-

```
private static bool delayFlag = false;
private static double delayTime = 0;

public static bool DelayGame(GameTime gameTime,int milliSeconds)
{
  if(delayFlag)
  {
    if(gameTime.TotalGameTime.TotalMilliseconds >= delayTime)
    {
      delayFlag = false;
      return true;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    delayFlag = true;
    delayTime = gameTime.TotalGameTime.TotalMilliseconds + milliSeconds;
  }
  return false;
}
```

I've used static everywhere so you won't have to worry where you call it from, enjoy and make great games